# Select top two events for the next month

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to fetch the two most recent events from the current month's date and display it on my homepage. However if the events dont exist for the current month I get a generic error. 
How can modify the query to check for the next month subsequently if the events in the current month are not found ?

```
dt = g1.return_dt("select  top  2  image_url,event_name,substring(description,1,80) as  description,Convert(nvarchar,Table_name.open_date,106) as open_date  from  Table_name where MONTH(open_date)=MONTH(getDate()) and YEAR(open_date)=YEAR(getDate()) order  by ID  desc");
```

Comment: What do you want to do if exactly one entry for the current month exists?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace WHERE statement with the great or equal conditions:

```
MONTH(open_date)>=MONTH(getDate()) and YEAR(open_date)>=YEAR(getDate())
```

In this case if there are no records for the current month then you get TOP 2 records from the next  month.

UPDATE: Or in the case if only one record exists in the current month and you need output it only.

```
where ( MONTH(open_date)=MONTH(getDate()) 
        and YEAR(open_date)=YEAR(getDate())
      )
      OR 
      (
        NOT EXISTS(select * from Table_name 
                    where MONTH(open_date)=MONTH(getDate()) 
                          and YEAR(open_date)=YEAR(getDate()) 
                   ) 
        AND 
        (MONTH(open_date)>=MONTH(getDate()) and YEAR(open_date)>=YEAR(getDate()))
      )
```

Comment: in case there is one event it will only fetch me that current event right ?

Comment: No it will be out one event from the current month and the next one from the next month.

Comment: i tried running it twice but it gives me the single event for novemember only

Comment: @user2735206: Today is the 1st of November so obviously you have only one record for the current month.

Comment: but according to you shouldn't the query fetch me the one event from december too if there is only one event in novemeber ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40356/discussion-between-user2735206-and-valex)